# When data sent to db via Postman port get crashed and that port dosent work futher in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web, backend

I'm trying laravel passport for authentication. And after reading it's documentation I coded below code lines and I'm trying to pass data like in the image via postman:

[image: Please click here to see the image]

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
class AuthController extends Controller
{
public function register(Request $request){
    $validationData = $request->validate([

        'email' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $user = User::firstOrNew(['email' => '$request->email']);
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = md5($request->password);
    $user->save();



  $http = new Client;
  $response = $http->post(url('oauth/token'), [

    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => '2',
        'client_secret' => 'WXXWDxYHfIPu5fbkSSTCnw56Gk0VJ271KDEd9NKr',
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'scope' =>'',
    ],
  ]);

return response (['data' => json_decode((string) $response->getBody(),  true)]);



}
public function login(){

}
}
```

When I checked database data it has been posted into the table but the request was not stopped until I stoped it . Then when I try to resend request it throws error saying email almost exist . I know its OK .But port 8016 dosen't response any more. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong here , Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to start with:

About postman..
You're using HTTP POST and not using the body, instead you're sending parameters on the url. Why using parameters instead of sending them in the body? (On the guzzle code, you're sending the content within the body).

Strip the validation within the method, if you're looking to validate the form, you can organize the code better if you create a set of validations elsewhere.

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#creating-form-requests

Please stop using md5, you've got a secret key within Laravel, hash it accordingly.

```
\Hash::make($request->password);    instead of    $user->password = md5($request->password);
```

If your request to your project is going to make a request to an external url, you need to take into consideration what may happen if the request fails for some reason (500, 404, 403). If you're going to request your own route, why are you using guzzle? You can call routes internally (even tho theres no need, if you need a functionality from your own code, you can just call it)

"When I check the database data has been posted into the table but the request sending will not be stopped utill i stop."

Most likely because of the HTTP Request you're making, as I said above, just call your own code functions internally and take out guzzle.

Comment: Dear Sir , Hens im new to laravel could you please highlight the error please

Comment: Remove this and your application won't stop

```$http = new Client;
  $response = $http->post(url('oauth/token'), [

    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => '2',
        'client_secret' => 'WXXWDxYHfIPu5fbkSSTCnw56Gk0VJ271KDEd9NKr',
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'scope' =>'',
    ],
  ]);```

Comment: If im right after removing that code there is no authentication ?

Comment: If you wrote the code, you should know what it does. The first block of code finds and updates (or create new) User into the database. The second block you are using an external package to access an url (What url are you trying to access???) The request freezes because of reaching an url that is taking too long to response (timeout)

Answer (score 1):

You have already checked the database that there?
probably have a record $request->email. Сannot write variables in single quotes
write so

```
$user = User::firstOrNew(['email' => $request->email]);
```

or

```
 $user = User::firstOrNew(['email' => "$request->email"]);
```